# Trying to update a row to a table on SQL server using python sql.connect lib datetime.datetime object causing syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, sqldatatypes

I am trying to update a table by getting rows from another table with the same structure using SQL connect library.

It has a column named **UTC_time** which is a **DateTime** datatype in the table and my value that I have is datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 3, 0, 0).

Lets say it is T = datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 3, 0, 0). When updating it gives a syntax error. Please tell me how can I fix this.

I tried converting timedate.timedate object (UTC_time) to string so that i can update it to the table

```
utctimestr = UTC_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

I expected that it will accept the string and update the UTC_time column of table B.

But, I am getting the same error as syntax error at line one UTC_time, other columns......

```
t = datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 20, 21, 28, 40)
```

I tried converting it to a string :

```
tt = t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Query :

```
 update_stmt = "UPDATE raw_tokenomics_data SET UTC_time=%s WHERE raw_tknomics_data_ID=1"
cursor.execute(update_stmt, (tt,))
connection.commit()
```

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UTC_time=''2021-11-20 21:28:40'' WHERE raw_tknomics_data_ID=1' at line 1
```

Comment: Please publish the sql statement.

Comment: And the exact error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show us an example of the string in `T`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - please provide a proper [mre], and also the versions of MySQL and the driver package involved.